# Why std::regex_match will return true?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++11

Can someone explain to me - why this code will return true after std::regex_match?

```
std::regex reg("(-)?(\\d)\{0,5\}(.)?(\\d)\{0,10\}");
std::string str("--");
std::regex_match(str, reg);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Another thing is, `{}` doesn't need escaping if you are using them to denote quantifiers. `\{` and `\}` are turned into `{` and `}` when the program is compiled, since they are not valid escape sequences. And there is no need to write `(-)?` or `(.)?`, write `-?` and `.?` (well, unless you want to capture them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you turned some  capturing groups to optional and  some capturing groups to repeat zero or more times.    `(\\d)\{0,5\}` repeats the previous  token `\\d` from 0 to 5 times. `(-)?` would turn the capturing group to optional. So `-` symbol may or maynot occurs. `.` is a special meta character in regex which matches any character except line breaks (*`\n`, `\r`*). But in DOTALL mode, dot would match also the line breaks (*In other languages*). To match a literal dot, you need to put the dot inside a character class like `[.]` or you need to escape the dot like `\\.`

```
     (-)?(\\d)\{0,5\}(.)?(\\d)\{0,10\}
      |               |
catures the first `-` | This captures the second `-`
```

And note that this regex also matches an empty string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/43)

Comment: hmm, but - and . are different signs, what should I do to tell the programm that - is minus and . is dot?

Comment: `.` is a special meta character in regex. To match a literal dot, you need to put the dot inside a character class like `[.]` or you need to escape the dot like `\\.`

Comment: thanks! but now I can't input up to 5 digits after - Instead of it I can enter much more digits. Looks strange

Comment: you need to include the start and end anchors. like `^(\\d)\{1,5\}$` allows one to 5 digits only.

Comment: There is no DOTALL mode in ECMAScript regex (which is what C++ regex is based on by default).

Comment: @AvinashRaj I've tried to add ^ and $ signs to my expression, but it doesn't work. Instead of it, I've changed regex to "(-)?(\\d){0,5}(\\.(\\d){0,10})?" and now it works well for me. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Because in `(-)?(\\d)\{0,5\}(.)?`, you match `-` optionally. Check. Then, `\\d` up to five times. Check. Then, anything goes with `.`. Check. The remainder is `\\d` again, up to ten times. Check.

The gist is in `-` and `.`, which match `-` and `-` again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to parse a number. You made a mistake: '.' means any symbol in regexp, so you should mask it to make it match only dot itself:

```
std::regex reg("(-)?(\\d)\{0,5\}(\\.)?(\\d)\{0,10\}");
```